# MATLAB morse code

Tags: matlab, function, return, morse-code

Write the function tokenizeSignal(signal) which takes the signal above and counts how many 0's and 1's appear in sequence. The output should be a 2D array where column 1 is how many appear and column 2 is which token it is (0 or 1). I have the following code that works until I put it inside a function. For example

```
sig =[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0];
tsig = abs(sig);  
dsig = diff([1 tsig 1]);
startIndex = find(dsig<0);
endIndex = find(dsig>0)-1;
duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
stringIndex = (duration >= 2);
d=find(stringIndex==0);
matA=[duration;zeros(1,size(duration,2))];
matA=matA';
wsig = abs(sig);  
rsig = diff([0 wsig 0]);
startIndex = find(rsig < 0);
endIndex = find(rsig > 0)-1;
duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
abs(duration);
stringIndex = (duration >= 2);
d=find(stringIndex==0);
type=[1];
matB=[ans;ones(1,size(ans,2))];
matB=matB';
token=reshape([matA(:) matB(:)]',size(matA,1)+size(matB,1), [])
```

this returns what we need but when we put the above code into a function header and type end at the conclusion it no longer returns anything. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because you rely on the keyword 
'ans', which is accessible from the workspace, not inside a function and refers to abs(duration)

This replicates your script, inside a function:

```
function   tokens = tokenizeSignal( sig )
tsig = abs(sig);  
dsig = diff([1 tsig 1]);
startIndex = find(dsig<0);
endIndex = find(dsig>0)-1;
duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
matA=[duration;zeros(1,size(duration,2))];
matA=matA';
wsig = abs(sig);  
rsig = diff([0 wsig 0]);
startIndex = find(rsig < 0);
endIndex = find(rsig > 0)-1;
duration = endIndex-startIndex+1;
yourAns = abs(duration);
matB=[yourAns;ones(1,size(yourAns,2))];
matB=matB';
tokens=reshape([matA(:) matB(:)]',size(matA,1)+size(matB,1), []) ;
```

Comment: thanks that was very helpful. Now I get an error because in some test conditions matA and matB are different sizes. How should I reshape them to get tokens?

Comment: You could return a cell array as in

Comment: tokens = {matA(:) ; matB(:)};

substitute the last line of the function with this one. HTH, PSS